# Statistics question related to sequence analysis

Tags: statistics

I have a statistics problem, which I can't get my head around.

I searching for the number of matches of a sequence of three nucleotides (GTG) and in a window of 9 nucleotides at a certain position within sequenced DNA fragments.

Based on computation using 1 million random 9 nucleotide sequences, I get a proportion p (=.1044) for 1 or more pattern matches of the 3 nucleotides within a random window.  Failure is 0 matches, success is 1 or more matches. This is my null statistic.

I want to use this null statistic p in order to produce a p value for my experimental proportion pex that I find when I look at a certain 9 bp window in a sequenced library (a ChIP-seq library, if anyone is interested).

So for example, I get 9896 positive outcomes (1 or more matches in the 9 bp window at a certain position relative to a motif in the fragment) for 62084 tested fragments.  pex = .1594

In R, why can I not use a binomial probability to determine the p value as 1 - pbinom(9895,62084, .1044), i.e, the probability of seeing 9896 or more positive outcomes.

I know I'm making some conceptual error, but I can't figure out what it is.
Thanks for any help.

Matt